# How can i add this progress bar js in my react app (beginner)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello there i want to add the progress bar js in my react application but I don't know how to do it , iam a beginner can someone please provide some help ?
the progressbarjs : is from https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/
so basically i must add this js code somewhere in my react :

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
  strokeWidth: 4,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#FFEA82',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: {width: '100%', height: '100%'},
  from: {color: '#FFEA82'},
  to: {color: '#ED6A5A'},
  step: (state, bar) => {
    bar.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
  }
});

bar.animate(1.0);
```

how to manage it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most probably wouldn't work as React doesn't know what ProgressBar is unless you include it in the project. It seems that its API is rather 'low-level' so why don't you look for some React made progress bars out there? Maybe it'll suit your needs better.

You can check out for example [MUI](https://mui.com/components/progress/), [Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/) or [some of the other](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-react-progress-bar-libraries) options out there.

Answer (score 2):

The same creator of ProgressBar.js has an npm library ([called react-progress-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-progressbar.js)) that may be more suited for your use in React without too much fiddling about.

The documentation seems comprehensive enough, but I'm indexing for the fact that you say you're a beginner, so here's an example of what a `<ProgressBar />` component can look like with this library:

```js
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function render() {
        var options = {
            strokeWidth: 2
        };
 
        // For demo purposes so the container has some dimensions.
        // Otherwise progress bar won't be shown
        var containerStyle = {
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px'
        };
 
        return (
            <Circle
                progress={this.state.progress}
                text={'test'}
                options={options}
                initialAnimate={true}
                containerStyle={containerStyle}
                containerClassName={'.progressbar'} />
        );
    }
});
```

There are many ways you may use the progress bar, but one common pattern is to use it as a loader, while waiting for data (example, from an axios call to a server/API).

That pattern usually looks like this:

```js
... //your React code
return (
   <div>
      {dataIsFetched? <span>{data.content}</span> : <ProgressBar />}
   </div>
)
```

Check out the [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-progressbar.js) for how to use it.

Comment: can you tell me where should i put this code

Comment: You should create a file and export it out from there, then import it as a component in the React app you want to use the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here a example for a circle progress bar

`

```
 import { Circle } from 'progressbar.js'
 import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function CircleProgress () {   
    useEffect(() => {
     var bar = new Circle('#container', {easing: 'easeInOut'});
     bar.animate(1);
   }, [])

    return (
      <div id="container"></div>
    )
}`
```